# How can I get my whatsapp number?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am developing an app for Android and want to read the whatsapp telephone number configured in the client device.

Tried the following code:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

for (Account ac : accounts) {
    String acname = ac.name;
    String actype = ac.type;
    // Take your time to look at all available accounts
    System.out.println("Accounts : " + acname + ", " + actype);
}

if(actype.equals("com.whatsapp")){
    String phoneNumber = ac.name;
}
```

I also set this permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`

but phoneNumber only returns "Whatsapp"

I need the user's whatsapp phone number as a record in my database. How can I get this phone number?

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. You need the `rawcontact` id of WhatsApp of that contact.
2. Query `ContactsContract.Data` table with `mimetype = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.profile"` with that `rawcontact` id.
3. The `DATA3` column is the number of WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp have updated their process, and they no longer create the account using the phone number as the account name, which is the trick this code relied upon.

I do not believe there is any way to now get hold of the WhatsApp phone number from outside the WhatsApp app.